# Not able to display user input date in datalist

Tags: html

I have an input field called creation date where user can enter date information. When user enter a date, that date should be listed in `<datalist>` automatically. But i am not getting expected result.

[image: result]

```html
Creation Date <input type="text" list="cdate" id="cdate" class="tb1">
  <datalist id="cdate">
     <option value="<%= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date())%>">UNIT 1</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: You mean, the date entered should be dynamically changed in the datalist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<datalist>` represents a set of options and need to be hooked to control element (`<input>` in this case). There is an `id` conflict between `<datalist>` and `<input>`. That's why the code snippet does not work.

However, even if the `id` conflict is fixed, this code may not work as you expected (if my understanding is right) -- The final result is: `<input>` element is able to select value from `<datalist>` options. The `<datalist>` content will not change dynamically due to `<input>` interaction.

Comment: Then what would be the correct method to get the expected result either current date (automatic list) or user has to give input

Comment: There are many ways to get the expected result. If you can use data-binding framework, such as AngularJS, React etc, it would be pretty simple: bind the displayed text to a variable X, and assign a default value to that variable X (current date in your case). After user input a new date, assign the new date to X and the displayed text will change automatically.

Comment: If you cannot use framework and only allowed to use jQuery, or even only allowed to use native JavaScript. The code would work like this: 1. display current date in html. 2. listen user input event. 3. when user input a new date, change the displayed date in html.

Comment: i can't use framework. let me go with second option.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you gave same ID `cdate` to input and datalist which is incorrect.

this is working example with javascript.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Creation Date <input type="text" list="cdate" class="tb1">
  <datalist id="cdate">
    </datalist>
    
 <script>
(function() {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    $('#cdate').append("<option value='" + todaysDate + "'>");

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above. changed code as

```html
Creation Date <input type="date" name="cdate" id="cdate" class="inp" value="<%= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date())%>"><br><br></p><br><br>
```

So that it will receive date from users also